# Post request to API is receiving NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core API that is expecting a POST request in the shape of a particular object -- see code sample below.

I make sure that my front-end client sends the data in that exact shape. I also make sure by inspecting my call with Fiddler that the data is being sent to the API.

When the request hits the API method though, it's `null`.

My first thought was that the model binder is the cause of the issue. Meaning, somehow, the data I'm sending is not matching the object my API method is expecting.

I've been staring at the code for a few hours now and it seems OK to me. Assuming that the shape of the object sent by the front-end matches the object my API is expecting, what else could be causing this issue?

I've been using similar code all over my app and everything is working fine.

My code looks like this:

```
[HttpPost("test")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething([FromBody]MyObject data)
{
   // Some logic here...
}
```

Here are a few things that I'm sure about:

1. I'm hitting the API method so there are no routing issues
2. The point above also confirms that my front-end client is sending a request
3. I know that my front-end client is sending data -- confirmed it through Fiddler

UPDATE:

This is definitely caused by model binder. I changed the code from `MyObject` to `dynamic` to see what would happen and sure enough I'm getting the data sent by the front-end. I haven't found the exact property that's causing the issue yet but I'm close. Here's what my API method looks like for now till I find the exact cause of the issue:

```
[HttpPost("test")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething([FromBody]dynamic data)
{
   // Some logic here...
}
```

UPDATE 2:
Found the issue!!!!

I had a `GUID` property with a `null` valud in it and the model binder didn't like it.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of MyObject and the request as seen in fiddler?

Comment: You're thinking the same thing. The object I'm sending is not matching the object API expects. I've been looking at that code for the last couple of hours. I'm trying to simplify the code I post here and the object is a bit complex. Other than objects not matching, can there be another issue? If not, I'll have to go back and spend more time making sure my objects match.

Comment: did you check the naming and does it match?

Comment: Is the front-end setting `Content-Type` to `application/json`?

Comment: The model binder is causing the issue. See update in original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This usually happens when your object can't be deserialized from JSON request.**

The best practice would be to **make sure that all the request properties can accept `null` values** (make value types properties are [nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)). And then you can validate that all your action needs is provided in the request and return [400 error](https://httpstatuses.com/400) if not.

Comment: Exactly right! I had to change the property that was expecting a `Guid` value to `Guid?` and that fixed the issue. Thanks!